# how do i install ubuntu onto a pre made partition?

Tags: system-installation

I am having trouble with the installation of Ubuntu, I have already gone through and made the partitions off my main disk from the Ubuntu installation, but it won't install. It's stuck at the part where it says "install (as superuser)" at the top of the page. What am I supposed to do?
[image]

I am stuck at this. ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Did you do a 'something else' install?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few issues occurring. I would recommend doing the following:

1. Run a disc check to ensure there are no errors on the Ubuntu CD/USB you created
2. When choosing "something else" during the install, delete the partitions you had created for Ubuntu and start over. I do the following:

> `/dev/sdaX linux-swap 4GiB` (or half the amount of ram you have)
>
> > `/dev/sdaX / 20 GiB` - (this is your root)
> >
> > > `/dev/sdaX /home` (rest of disk space /home partition is also optional)

I format all my partitions to `Btrfs` format as well, this runs the smoothest for me.

3. Ensure that you have your power supply as well as a good Ethernet connection plugged in.

As installation can take some time and if you are running a live CD/USB you want to be sure your Internet connection is consistent for the install.

Then follow the installation as normal. Sometimes depending on the amount of ram installed and your graphics card, it can take about thirty minutes or so to install.